# Why are some images garbled in the HTML report generated by ydata-profiling?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pandas-profiling

`train = pd.read_csv(file_name,encoding="utf-8") profile = ppf.ProfileReport(train)  profile.to_file('train-cls.html')`

[image]

I have rebuilt the rcmod.py of seaborn, but the question isn't solved.